# How to remove the empty style attribute that jQuery leaves behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Some people know that jQuery leaves a blank style attribute in the body tag:

```
<body style></body>
```

Though this is harmless, it sort of bothers me. I have this script to remove the blank style tag:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].removeAttribute("style");
```

But it doesn't work and leaves the style tag there.

**How can I write a script that actually removes the blank style tag?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of these worked for me:

Using jQuery: `$('body').removeAttr('style');`

Using regular ol' DOM: `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeAttribute('style');`

Comment: Really? [Check this out](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp)

Comment: Oh, my bad. You said you were using jQuery, I got confused.

Comment: @Bill F. Is there any way to make this happen for all elements in the DOM?

Comment: @Narong, sure there is, but it's important to ask yourself if this is really necessary. If you have a really big DOM with lots of HTML elements, do you really want Javascript/jQuery recursively checking all of them for empty style elements? Doubtful.

Comment: I wasn't planning on having it run continuously. I was just going to have a function to "clean" the code whenever I need to export the code generated dynamically.

Comment: @Narong If you're not worried about performance, you can simply use the $('*') selector to inspect all elements. You could also use the jQuery selector that matches on attribute values to find all elements with empty style attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to clean up a leftover `style` tag after styles are removed, then you can do a check to see if the `style` tag is empty, and then remove it, otherwise you might inadvertently remove styles you were unaware of:

```js
const element = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
const styleTagIsEmpty = element.getAttribute("style") === "";
if (styleTagIsEmpty) element.removeAttribute("style");
```